# Python inplace Boolean operator

Tags: python-3.x, operators, augmented-assignment

Python has [inplace operators](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#inplace-operators) such as `-=` and `|=` for arithmetic and bit operations:

```
FLAG_FOO = 1 << 0
FLAG_BAR = 1 << 1
mask = FLAG_FOO
mask |= FLAG_BAR
assert mask == 3 == FLAG_FOO | FLAG_BAR
```

Is there an equivalent for actual `True`/`False` Booleans?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26409572/320036), bitwise `&` (and) and `|` (or) work fine for `bool` variables:

```
foo = False
foo |= True
assert foo == True == False | True == False or True
```

When not using inplace operators, it's more idiomatic to use the logical `and` and `or` operators. It can be confusing to use the bit operators on Booleans, because e.g. `~True` is `-2`, not `False`.