# Are & and <and> equivalent in python?

Tags: python, operators, bitwise-operators, boolean-operations

Is there any difference in the logic or performance of using the word `and` vs. the `&` symbol in Python?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22646463/4873159)

Comment: Try `1 and 1 and 2` and `1 & 1 & 2`

Comment: @FlashDrive Your linked question is related but too long. It gets into too much into numpy and lists. The question here is simple and deserves a simple answer.

Comment: So I don't think the linked question is a good reference for a duplicate. But if there is a more straightforward Q&A on this topic, then I will concede to that one instead as the duplicate.

Comment: I'm not clear on what I'm supposed to do with this question. Should I erase it because it has a lot of overlap with the question @FlashDrive cited?

Comment: @Alex I think your question is a good question. Please let it stand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`and` is a Boolean operator. It treats both arguments as Boolean values, returning the first if it's falsy, otherwise the second. Note that if the first is falsy, then the second argument isn't even computed at all, which is important for avoiding side effects.

Examples:

- `False and True --> False`
- `True and True --> True`
- `1 and 2 --> 2`
- `False and None.explode() --> False` (no exception)

---

`&` has two behaviors.

- If both are `int`, then it computes the bitwise AND of both numbers, returning an `int`. If one is `int` and one is `bool`, then the `bool` value is coerced to int (as 0 or 1) and the same logic applies.
- Else if both are `bool`, then both arguments are evaluated and a `bool` is returned.
- Otherwise a `TypeError` is raised (such as `float & float`, etc.).

Examples:

- `1 & 2 --> 0`
- `1 & True --> 1 & 1 --> 1`
- `True & 2 --> 1 & 2 --> 0`
- `True & True --> True`
- `False & None.explode() --> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'explode'`