# conditional statement acting abnormal

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

```
def signUp():
    id=input("enter your id")
    password=input("enter your password")
    if (len(id) == 9 & len(password) > 4):
        print("YOUR ACCOUNT IS CREATED.....")
    else:
        print("Invalid ID or password")
```

Although I'm giving ID of length 9 and password of length greater than 4, still the condition isn't working. It's going to else always. But if I'm using nested if for ID and password, it's working fine.

Could you please help.

Comment: Use the `and` keyword, not the `&` operator here. `&` is a bitwise "and" operation which works on integers, and has a higher precedence than `==`, so this code is definitely not doing what you intended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are & and <and> equivalent in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941097/are-and-and-equivalent-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is bit-wise AND.  You want logical `and`:

```
if len(id) == 9 and len(password) > 4:
```