# If statement ordering and key error python

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, keyerror

Here I get a key error even I check if the key exists in the dict :

```
def foo(d):
    if (('element' in d.keys()) & (d['element'] == 1)):
        print "OK"

foo({})
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) we can read :

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

Can anybody explain me this behavior?

Comment: try replacing '&' with 'and'

Comment: You are looking at the documentation for `and` and executing `&`, the documentation for which is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) (on the same page).

Comment: why are you calling foo() with an empty dict?

Comment: Actually I already CV'd but this is probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is "bitwise and",  `and` is the logical "and" operator, they are not the same thing.

You should use `and`, and you can also remove the unneeded parenthesis for readability.

You also don't even have to call the `keys` method:

`if 'element' in d and d['element'] == 1:`

Comment: Or condense to `if d.get('element'):` since get automatically returns `None` (which is falsy).

Comment: Perhaps `if d.get('element') == 1:` to preserve the other part of the `if` statement