# the use of boolean logic "and" and bitwise operator "&"

Tags: python, boolean, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic

sorry about this basic question, I just a beginner in Python programming.
From my undertsanding, & and "and" are the same things, and "&" is just a shorhand for "and" so if I use Python's dataframe

```
df[ (df.StateAb == "NSW") & (df.PartyAb == "LP") ]
```

this compliles OK,but if I type

```
df[ (df.StateAb == "NSW") and (df.PartyAb == "LP") ]
```

then it cannot be compiled correctly.

so what's the difference between "and" and "&",

Comment: You can refer these things. [2] [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i]

Comment: The hint is in the name. The boolean operator behaves according to the rules of boolean logic; the bitwise operator performs bitwise arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one useful:

```
1 and 2
>> 2

1 & 2
>> 0
```

The first result is due to short circuiting. Python tests 1 and finds it true and returns the 2. But, the second part does 01 (Binary 1) & 10 (Binary 2) hence evaluating to 00 (1 & 0, 0 &1) , which is 0.

Comment: You have "first" and "second" backwards in your explanation.