# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python pandas. I build a small function and now I always get the following error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I know that this error was already discussed in other question, however I do not really get what I should do different and how the error occurred.

So this is my simple function:

```
def relativeWinner():
    if df['GoldSummer'] >0 & df['GoldWinter'] >0:
        df['diff'] = abs(df['GoldSummer'] - df['GoldWinter'])/(df['GoldSummer'] + df['GoldWinter'])
    return df['diff'].idxmax()
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here and how i would fix it?

Comment: What happens if df['GoldSummer'] or df['GoldWinter'] are not greater than 0? You might need an 'else' statement.

Comment: You can't compare arrays to generate a scalar value, it should be rewritten like so:
`def relativeWinner():
    df.loc[(df['GoldSummer'] >0) & (df['GoldWinter'] >0), 'diff'] -= ((df['GoldSummer'] - df['GoldWinter'])/(df['GoldSummer'] + df['GoldWinter'])).abs()
    return df['diff'].idxmax()`. Besides if your condition is not met it'll just return the index label of the max diff value, is this intended?

Comment: Think about what `df['GoldSummer'] >0 & df['GoldWinter'] >0` returns... it returns a series of booleans: `[True, True, False, True, False]`. You pass this to an if-condition, but `pandas` does not know what you want to consider such an array as...should it be `True` because it has at least one `True` (then use `.any()`), should it be `False` because not all are `True`? (use `all`). Perhaps you want to check if the Series has any values, (use `.empty`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga where do I put that .any() or .all()?

Comment: You could do something like `if (df['GoldSummer'] >0 & df['GoldWinter'] >0).all():`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so now i added '.all()' as you said, however I still get the same error, do I have to add a else part or why is the error still here?

Comment: @threxx Ah! This one bites me a lot: the precedence of the `&` operator messes things up, be explicit: `if ((df['GoldSummer'] >0) & (df['GoldWinter'] >0)).all():` In other words, the bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `^`) have higher precedence than the comparison operators (`<`, `>`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that worked! Thanks. But why do I need to add brackets here ?

Comment: Because of operator precedence. `(df['GoldSummer'] >0 & df['GoldWinter'] >0)` ... `0 & df['GoldWinter']` is reduced first (in this case, using a vectorized bitwise and!), leaving you with a comparison with another series! bringing you back the the original problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why this specific issue is occurring, see this post:

[Difference between 'and' (boolean) vs. '&' (bitwise) in python. Why difference in behavior with lists vs numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

Regarding your code, try this instead:

```
df['diff'] = [abs(tup[0] - tup[1]) / tup[0] if (tup[0] > 0) and (tup[1] > 0) else 'NaN' for tup in zip(df['GoldSummer'], df['GoldWinter'])]
```