# Multiple conditions np.extract

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array and want ot extract all entries which are in a specific range

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
condition = x<=4 and x>1
x_sel = np.extract(condition,x)
```

But this does not work. I'm getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If I'm doing the same without the and and checking for example only one condition

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
condition = x<=4 
x_sel = np.extract(condition,x)
```

everything works...
Of courese I could just apply the procedure twice with one condition, but isn't there a solution to do this in one line?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using `&` instead `and` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
condition = (x<=4) & (x>1)
x_sel = np.extract(condition,x)
```

Mind the usage of `and` and `&`:
[Difference between 'and' (boolean) vs. '&' (bitwise) in python. Why difference in behavior with lists vs numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can use either this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
condition = (x <= 4) & (x > 1)
x_sel = np.extract(condition,x)
print(x_sel)
# [2 3 4]
```

Or this without `extract`:

```
x_sel = x[(x > 1) & (x <= 4)]
```