# Replacing numpy array elements within a given range then and there

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have following numpy array.

```
arr = np.array( [ 1.0, 1.1, 1.44, 1.8, 1.0, 1.67, 1.23, 1.0] )
```

I could replace all elements that are equal to 1.0 with 0.0, simply using following line.

```
arr[arr==1.0] = 0.0
```

How could I replace all elements between, say 1.0 - 1.5 with 1.0 without running through a for loop.

Basically what I ask is how to do the following

```
arr[arr>1.0 and arr<1.5] = 1.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Difference between 'and' (boolean) vs. '&' (bitwise) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to club the conditions together using `&` and enclosing the conditions in `( )`

```
arr[(arr>1.0) & (arr<1.5)] = 1.0

# array([1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.8 , 1.  , 1.67, 1.  , 1.  ])
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how this operation happens, and why it is faster than replacing with a for loop?

Comment: `(arr>1.0)` and `(arr<1.5)` finds the indices for which the conditions are True and `&` combines them. The result is the indices at which the values fulfill these conditions. Those indices inside `[ ]` acts as the input indices for `arr[ ]` and gives you the elements for which the condition holds. The assignment operator `=` then assigns 1.0 to the values on those indices.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
arr = np.array( [ 1.0, 1.1, 1.44, 1.8, 1.0, 1.67, 1.23, 1.0] )
arr[(1<arr) & (arr<1.5)] = 1.0
```

You need to use the bit-wise `&` to join the arrays into one array mask.