# Can numpy/pandas handle boolean operators acting on null values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If I use the standard Python boolean operators `and`/`or`/`not`, one nice feature is that they treat `None` the way I would logically expect. That is, not only

```
True and True == True
True and False == False
```

but also

```
True and None == None
False and None == False
True or None == True
False or None == None
```

This follows the logic that, for instance, if A is False and B is unknown, (A and B) must still be False, while (A or B) is unknown.

I needed to perform boolean operations on Pandas DataFrames with missing data, and was hoping I'd be able to use the same logic. For boolean logic on numpy arrays and Pandas series, we need to use bitwise operators `&`/`|`/`~`. Pandas seems to have behaviour that is partially the same as `and`/`or`/`not`, but partially different. In short, it seems to return `False` when the value should logically be unknown.

For example:

```
a = pd.Series([True,False,True,False])
b = pd.Series([True,True,None,None])
```

Then we get

```
> a & b
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

and

```
> a | b
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
```

I would expect that the output of `a & b` should be a Series `[True,False,None,False]` and that the output of `a | b` should be a Series `[True,True,True,None]`. The actual result matches what I'd expect except returns `False` instead of any missing values.

Finally, `~b` just gives a TypeError:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'NoneType'

which seems odd since `&` and `|` at least partially work.

Is there a better way to carry out boolean logic in this situation? Is this a bug in Pandas?

Analogous tests with numpy arrays just give type errors, so I assume Pandas is handling the logic itself here.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this:

```
c = pd.Series([x and y for x,y in zip(a,b)])

print(c)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     None
3    False
```

And correspondingly, for the second expression:

```
d = pd.Series([x or y for x,y in zip(a,b)])

print(d)
```

Output:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    None
```

also look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i) for understanding `and` and `&` operations.

---

If you want to `and` two columns `a` and `b` of a dataframe `df`, one way is to define a function and apply it to `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[True,False,True,False], 'b':[True,True,None,None]})
def and_(row):
    return row['a'] and row['b']
df.loc[:, 'a_and_b'] = df.apply(and_, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       a     b a_and_b
0   True  True    True
1  False  True   False
2   True  None    None
3  False  None   False
```

Comment: I know I can work with lists, but it loses the advantages of vectorisation, and the code will be clunkier for DataFrames. I was hoping for a way to use pandas- or numpy-native functionality.

Comment: I think you can not do an element-wise `and` by just `a and b` when `a` and `b` are series (while you could do element-wise `&`). In case you want to `and` two columns of a dataframe, look at the revised answer.