# difference between "&" and "and" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some code that runs on a cron (via kubernetes) for several months now.

Yesterday, part of my code didn't work that normally does:

This statement, all of a sudden, wasnt 'True' (both df_temp and df_temp4 have data in them:

```
if ( len(df_temp > 0) & len(df_temp4 > 0)):
    print "HERE"
```

however, this worked:

```
if ( len(df_temp > 0) and len(df_temp4 > 0)):
    print "HERE"
```

Was there some sort of code push that would cause this change? Since I've run this code for months, not sure what would cause this statement to fail all of a sudden.

Comment: I guess their lengths didn't have any overlapping bits this time.

Comment: what do you mean by that? @tkausl

Comment: Well, `&` is the __bitwise__ and operator.

Comment: strange that it always worked - so the proper syntax is to use "and"?

Comment: Incidentally, is `len(df_temp > 0)` meant to count the number of positive values in `df_temp`? If so, you probably want to use something like `(df_temp > 0).sum()` instead.

Comment: Unless you want the bitwise operation; yes.

Comment: `len(df_temp > 0)` is used to check if data is there

Comment: @DerekKrantz: in that case you can write `len(df_temp) > 0` or even just `len(df_temp)` - i.e. your condition sould be `if len(df_temp) and len(df_temp4):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `len(df_temp > 0)` and `len(df_temp4 > 0)` probably don't do what you expect. The comparison operators with pandas DataFrames return element-wise results, that means they create a boolean DataFrame where each value indicates if the corresponding value in the DataFrame is greater than zero:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-1,0,1], 'b': [-1,0,1]})
>>> df
   a  b
0 -1 -1
1  0  0
2  1  1
>>> df > 0
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
```

So the `len` of `df` is the same as the `len` of `df > 0`:

```
>>> len(df)
3
>>> len(df > 0)
3
```

> difference between "&" and "and"

They mean different things:

- `&` is [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)
- `and` is [logical and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) (and short-circuiting)

Since you asked specifically about pandas (assuming at least one operand is a NumPy array, pandas Series, or pandas DataFrame):

- `&` also refers to the element-wise "bitwise and".
- The element-wise "logical and" for pandas isn't `and` but one has to use a function, i.e. [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).

For more explanation you can refer to ["Difference between 'and' (boolean) vs. '&' (bitwise) in python. Why difference in behavior with lists vs numpy arrays?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

> not sure what would cause this statement to fail all of a sudden.

You did not provide the "fail" nor the expected behavior so unfortunately I cannot help you there.

Answer (score 4):

They have completely different behavior. 
When you use `and`, you are comparing boolean values, but when you use `&` you are element-wising logical and. I suggest you to read this complete answer to learn more.
[Logic operator for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame([True, False])
dfb = pd.DataFrame([False, False])

print(dfa & dfb)
#    0
# 0  False
# 1  False

print(dfa and dfb)
# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: your answer is not correct. If you want element-wise logical-and in pandas, please use the & binary operator performs

Answer (score 0):

You replaced wrongly applied bit operator `&` with proper logical `and` operator.

First of all, you should use `and` operator because what you really want is a logical expression with logical operators.

Bitwise `&` operator failed when lengths had no common bits.

Try the following in Python.

```
True and 1 & 1
True and 1 & 2
```

Comment: more specifically, I'm confused why this statement:df_temp = df[(df.funding_date >= beginning_of_month) & (df.funding_date <= yesterday) & ( df.state != 'MO')] - needs an "&" operator but the if statement needs an "and" operator

Answer (score 0):

Logically the two statements are different.
The & indicate bitwise operator.
The AND indicates a logical and.