# count dataframe rows where two particular columns have the same, particular value, output number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can i count the number of rows in which two columns of a given df have the same, particular value? I want to obtain only the number of such rows, so maybe there is a better solution than just double groupby?

I was thinking about something like that:
`rows = (data['col1'] == 0 and data['col2']==0).sum()`

but while it works with only one condition, then when adding the second one I get an error saying `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`.

Comment: `(data['col1'].eq(0) & data['col2'].eq(0)).sum()`  or `((data['col1'] == 0) & (data['col2'] == 0)).sum()`

Comment: Take a look at [difference between “&” and “and” in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54315627/15497888)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, exactly what I wanted.