# Pandas filter rows of data frame where value is below 10 and greather then 1000

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove the rows where Área is below 10 and above 1000.

So this works perfectly:

```
x = dataset[(dataset['Área'] > 10) ]
```

But this doesn't:

```
x = dataset[(dataset['Área'] > 10) and (dataset['Área'] < 1000)]
```

Please explain. I'm following this tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp).

Thank you.

Comment: `x = dataset[(dataset['Área'] > 10) & (dataset['Área'] < 1000)]`

Comment: Use `&` instead of `and`

Comment: ['and' (boolean) vs '&' (bitwise) - Why difference in behavior with lists vs numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22646463/15497888), [difference between “&” and “and” in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54315627/15497888), [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21415661/15497888)

Comment: Maybe use the "&" symbol instead of "and".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That it because `and` is logical and, ie. `True and False` will yield `False`. You need bitwise-and, ie. `&`.

Try:

```
x = dataset[(dataset['Área'] > 10) & (dataset['Área'] < 1000)]
```