# Filtering a dataframe using a list of values as parameter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this dataframe:

```
id   check_id
1       10
1       100
2       10
3       34
4       12
1       101
```

and a list:

```
list=[10,101]
```

I am trying to filter this df like this:

```
df[(df['id']==1) and (df['check_id'].isin(list))]
```

To get this output:

```
id   check_id
1       10
1       101
```

but I get this error msg:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've been trying to solve it but no sucess so far.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use `&` not `and`. Also you really shouldn't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you had searched instead of asking the question, you would have easily got the answer

```
df[(df['id']==1) & (df['check_id'].isin(list))]
```

Comment: Editing your answer to add snark does not improve the situation. Furthermore, you should've known to search for the duplicate and link it instead of answering.

Comment: answered because someone following all of my answer.  I've never had similar answer. I don't think this is problem

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315627/difference-between-and-and-in-pandas)
, the query should be:

```
df[(df['id']==1) & (df['check_id'].isin(list))]
```