# Difference between using 'and' and using '&' in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have Query which shows different results when i use **and** or **&**

```
criteria1 = Q(id__gte=802, id__lte=1000)
criteria2 = Q(country_id__contains='UK')
```

I always have been using :

```
q = Mymodel.objects.filter(criteria1 & criteria2)
```

But in this particular case when i use **&**  it always outputs a single row .
*(I also checked print **q.query()**, query comes out to be  fine)*

However, when i use **and** instead of **&**. Query gives correct output

```
q = Mymodel.objects.filter(criteria1 and criteria2)
```

what actually is happening under the hood ?

Comment: `and` is not a operator that is specially implemented for `Q` objects. It will be evaluated by the normal Python rules as `criteria1 if not criteria1 else criteria2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct one is `criteria1 & criteria2`. `criteria1 and criteria2` uses standard Python boolean logic and will be evaluated into `criteria2`, while `criteria1 & criteria2` uses overloaded `__and__` method and constructs correct compound `Q` object:

```
In [1]: from django.db.models import Q                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [2]: criteria1 = Q(id__gte=802, id__lte=1000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [3]: criteria2 = Q(country_id__contains='UK')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [4]: criteria1 & criteria2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[4]: <Q: (AND: ('id__gte', 802), ('id__lte', 1000), ('country_id__contains', 'UK'))>

In [5]: criteria1 and criteria2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[5]: <Q: (AND: ('country_id__contains', 'UK'))>
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying this ....Using *and* is completly wrong .  When i use *&*  and run the same raw query in mysql  it returns more than one row but orm returns single row ! ...Should this question  be included in other thread ?

Comment: Yes, please. Create a new question and include the actual code and SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

`Q` object define magic method `__or__` and `__and__`. These functions allow `&` math and `|` operation to be overridden. Check [this document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.and_)

And if you want to know about difference between `and` and `&`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)

This is [Q object code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/query_utils/#Q). You can find below code.

```
class Q(tree.Node):
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self._combine(other, self.OR)

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self._combine(other, self.AND)
```

Comment: No. `__or__` and `__and__` map to `|` and `&`, not `or` and `and`.

Comment: I got it wrong. I'm sorry. And thank you for your comments. @DanielRoseman