# In python, how are Boolean values & used?

Tags: python

`print(1!=1 & 1!=1)`
`print(1!=1 & 2!=2)`
Why do the two return different values?

Comment: `&` and `|` are bitwise operators in python.

Comment: use `and`, as `&` means something else. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i

Answer (score 6):

`&` has a higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `!=`, so your statements are equivalent to

```
print(1!=(1 & 1)!=1)
print(1!=(1 & 2)!=2)
```

1&1 is 1, and 1&2 is 0,* so these are equivalent to

```
print(1!=1!=1)
print(1!=0!=2)
```

Because `!=` supports [chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), these are equivalent to

```
print((1!=1) and (1!=1))
print((1!=0) and (0!=2))
```

Which is equivalent to

```
print(False and False)
print(True and True)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
print(False)
print(True)
```

(*If you're thinking "that's strange, I thought 1 and 2 were both True when evaluated in a boolean context. Shouldn't and-ing them together evaluate to True?", that only works if you use the boolean AND operator `and` rather than the bitwise AND operator `&`.)