# Change all of one number to another number in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a numpy array:

```
[[2, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 2, 1]]
```

How do I change all of the twos to be ones?

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

There are naive ways to do it that are *really* slow (i.e. looping through every entry). I have to do it on a large dataset, so a fast solution is essential.

Comment: if memory and speed is a concern, you may consider using [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr), which gives you a good tradeoff for using `numpy` vectorized operations in memory efficient [*and often faster* way](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this quickly enough using a mask:

```py
x[x == 2] = 1
```

You can also apply more complicated masks (with [bitwise python operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i)) if you have other numbers that you want to convert to ones:

```py
x[(x == 2) | (x == 3)] = 1
```