# How to set pandas value by another value with any conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I need to change values by another values with any conditions in pandas dataframe, but get error:

```
>>> df
      X0  X1  X2
0      a   1  0
1      b   3  0
2      c   2  0
3      c   4  0
```

formula:
if (X0 != "a" and X0 != "b") set X2 = X0+X1

result will be :

```
>>> df
      X0  X1  X2
0      a   1  0
1      b   3  0
2      c   2  c2
3      c   4  c4
```

I try to use:

```
df.loc[df.X0!= "a" and df.X0!= "b" ,"X2"]= df.X1+dfX2
```

but get " ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X0':['a','b','c','c'],'X1':[1,3,2,4],'X2':[0,0,0,0]})
```

You got the error because you didn't have parenthesis and didn't use the "&" operator.  If you want to do it with `.loc`, this works:

```
df.loc[(df.X0 != "a") & (df.X0 != "b"), "X2"]= df.X0 + df.X1.astype(str)

print(df)
  X0  X1  X2   
0  a   1   0    
1  b   3   0   
2  c   2   c2  
3  c   4   c4
```

Comment: Hi Rick! Please explain my fault:
why do you use  bitwise  "&"  instead  "and" ?

Comment: I've  got a warning:
"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)"

Comment: Hi there... it's because you're doing a *vectorized* element-by-element bitwise comparison of two numpy boolean arrays, and numpy uses the `&` operator for that.  Each expression in parenthesis is a 4 element numpy array of True/False. You get an error when using `and` because it tries to compare the two arrays as a whole, and numpy doesn't allow that. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/and-boolean-vs-bitwise-why-difference-in-behavior-with-lists-vs-nump .

Comment: The `SettingWithCopyWarning` usually means that you're working on a view of a dataframe that you've already selected a subset of in an earlier step, like `df = df_orig[condition]` . If that's the case, you can do `df = df_orig[condition].copy()` to eliminate the warning.

Comment: And what is more efficiently method   np.where or  loc.[]?

Comment: I'm not sure it's generally true that one is more efficient than the other; you can certainly find a number of SO questions on it if you explore here. My thought is that if you need that level of optimization, you can test the timing on your actual code or a subset of your data. For example, if it's in a Jupyter notebook you can use `%%timeit` at the top of the cell to get a measurement of performance.

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way is to use `np.where`, and correctly state your conditions:

```
import numpy as np
df['X2'] = np.where((df['X0'] != 'a') & (df['X0'] !='b'),df[['X0','X1']].astype(str).apply(''.join,1),0)
```

which prints:

```
df
Out[47]: 
  X0  X1  X2
0  a   1   0
1  b   3   0
2  c   2  c2
3  c   4  c4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution.
If you have some questions, feel free to ask.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'X0':['a','b','c','c'],'X1':[1,3,2,4],'X2':[0,0,0,0]})
_condition1 = dff.X0 != 'a'
_condition2 = dff.X0 != 'b'
dff['X2'] = np.where(_condition1&_condition2,dff.X0+dff.X1.astype(str),0)
dff
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It's more clear than the previous one.

Comment: (I mean "sophods" post)

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it.