# "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" error [Python]

Tags: python, numpy

`index = np.where(slopes > mean - 2 * sd and slopes < mean + 2 * sd)[0]`

returns this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

If I instead write `idx = np.where(slopes < mean + 2 * sd)[0]` or `idx = np.where(slopes > mean - 2 * sd)[0]` I get the right indices. Why can't I combine both conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **boolean 'and'**:

```
index = np.where((slopes > mean - 2 * sd) and (slopes < mean + 2 * sd))[0]
```

Try your code with **bitwise '&'**:

```
index = np.where((slopes > mean - 2 * sd) & (slopes < mean + 2 * sd))[0]
```

**Note:** For more Information regarding **boolean 'and'** and **bitwise '&'** you can refer to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/and-boolean-vs-bitwise-why-difference-in-behavior-with-lists-vs-nump)

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!