# ESP-Now data throughput logging on GPS coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, gps, nmea

I'm using two ESP32 boards for ESP-Now communication, where one ESP is sending packets and while the other is receiving them while logging this data together with GPS to measure throughput at a certain coordinate for me to get throughput rate while moving and changing rate between sender and receiver.

ESP32 receiver and GPS module is connected to Rpi that is running a script of reading the data from serial com ports, parsing it, and writing it to a file.

```
import serial
import time
import pandas as pd

# Receiver
esp_com = '/dev/ttyUSB1'
esp_baud = 115200
ser = serial.Serial(port=esp_com, baudrate=esp_baud, timeout=0.1)

# GPS
gps_com = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
gps_baud = 4800
sergps = serial.Serial(port=gps_com, baudrate=gps_baud, timeout=0.1)

# title of the file to write data in
title = 'ESP-NOW LoRa'

# time step at which data is logged
timestep = 1

# create lists
XCV = []

# initial dropped/received packets data
drp = 0
rcv = 0
counter = 0

waiting_for_recv = False

# outputs empty data table
df = pd.DataFrame()

# outputs time in seconds since the timer started
then = time.time()
then1 = time.time()

# clear ESP buffers
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

# initial data
RECEIVED = 0
RECEIVED = []
LAT = []
LON = []
T = []
t = 0
gpsdata = ''

# loop
while True:
    try:
        xcv = ser.readline().decode()  # decodes string
        if xcv != '':
            xcv = xcv.split("\r\n")
            for x in xcv:
                if x != '':
                    print(x)
                    XCV.append(x)
                    if 'RECV' in x:
                        RECEIVED = int(x[4:])  # sliced first 4 characters

        while True:
            cvb = sergps.readline()
            if cvb != b'':
                if 'GNGGA' in cvb.decode():
                    gpsdata = cvb.decode()
            else:
                break

        now = time.time()

        if now > then+timestep:
            print(now)
            df.at[counter, 'timestamp'] = now
            df.at[counter, 'received'] = RECEIVED
            drp = 0
            rcv = 0

            RECEIVED = 0
            then = now

            counter += 1

            vbn = gpsdata.split(',')
            if('GNGGA' in vbn[0]) & (vbn[2] != "") & (len(vbn) >= 5):
                print('GPS has a fix')
                tt = vbn[1]
                lat = vbn[2]
                lon = vbn[4]
                lat = int(lat[0:2])+float(lat[2:])/60
                lon = int(lon[0:3])+float(lon[3:])/60
                LAT.append(lat)
                LON.append(lon)
                T.append(t)
                t += 1
                print('LAT: {}, LON: {}'.format(lat, lon))

            else:
                print('GPS does not have a fix')
                LAT.append(0)
                LON.append(0)

            # write data to file every 30 seconds
            if now > then1+30:
                then1 = now
                # print GPS dataframe to columns
                df['lat'] = LAT
                df['lon'] = LON
                df.to_excel(title+'.xlsx')  # writes data to excel file

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I ran into a problem, where once GPS has a fix, and starts sending full NMEA messages with coordinates, received/dropped packet data gets lost, and the whole script hangs. I can see in my variables that GPS NMEA data is parsed correctly and when GPS does not have a fix, everything works, but once it starts sending full NMEA messages with coordinates the script breaks.

I can't really figure it out myself why, and I think that the code itself needs optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I see it's been a while, but I have bumped in to this post.

So one issue I see:

```
while True:
    cvb = sergps.readline()
    if cvb != b'':
         if 'GNGGA' in cvb.decode():
             gpsdata = cvb.decode()
    else:
        break
```

Here you will stuck in the loop while the ANY data is coming from GPS module. You might want to break also after you get `gpsdata`.

One other thing here you have boolean values so use `and` (logical) and not `&` (bitwise):

```
vbn = gpsdata.split(',')
    if('GNGGA' in vbn[0]) & (vbn[2] != "") & (len(vbn) >= 5):
        print('GPS has a fix')
```

Read more here: ['and' (boolean) vs '&' (bitwise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/and-boolean-vs-bitwise-why-difference-in-behavior-with-lists-vs-nump)